# store jquery selector over page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is it possible to store a jQuery selector for a unique dom object and re-use it after a page reload?

```
$('body')
.on('click', '*', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var whatIwanttostore = $(this);
});
```

I considered navigating up the DOM, storing the index of the element and constructing a selector that looks like `$('div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(4)')` or perhaps doing that but only going up as far as the closest element with an id but that doesn't seem like the best way of doing it.

Comment: If you know the ways to do it with client side technologies, then you are set

Comment: Are you assuming the page is completely static and that nothing is going to change between one page load and the next, and there is nothing else in play which could potentially manipulate the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to store is a jQuery object, not a selector, and this is not possible. A page is stateless and knows (almost) nothing about the previous page.

If you wanted to store the selector (for example 'div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(4)'), you could use cookies, or sessionStorage/localStorage in modern browsers.

Comment: @marmite to clarify, you could store a selector, since a selector is just a string, but you could not store a jQuery object (the actual collection of elements), if for no other reason, because those elements will not exist in the next page load. having the same page structure is not the same as having the exact same elements. also, chances are there is a far easier way to do whatever it is that you want to do, but from your question we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, the jQuery object is what I wanted to store. As that's not possible, I will attempt my navigating up the DOM solution.

Comment: @marmite also consider reloading only a fraction of the page to avoid the issue.